# I'm getting different results every time I run my code

Tags: java, cluster-analysis, elki

I'm using `ELKI` to cluster my data I used `KMeansLloyd<NumberVector>`  `with k=3`  every time I run my java code I'm getting totally different clusters results, is this normal or there is something I should do to make my output nearly stable?? here my code that I got from elki tutorials

```
DatabaseConnection dbc = new ArrayAdapterDatabaseConnection(a);
    // Create a database (which may contain multiple relations!)
    Database db = new StaticArrayDatabase(dbc, null);
    // Load the data into the database (do NOT forget to initialize...)
    db.initialize();
    // Relation containing the number vectors:
    Relation<NumberVector> rel = db.getRelation(TypeUtil.NUMBER_VECTOR_FIELD);
    // We know that the ids must be a continuous range:
    DBIDRange ids = (DBIDRange) rel.getDBIDs();

    // K-means should be used with squared Euclidean (least squares):
    //SquaredEuclideanDistanceFunction dist = SquaredEuclideanDistanceFunction.STATIC;
    CosineDistanceFunction dist= CosineDistanceFunction.STATIC;

    // Default initialization, using global random:
    // To fix the random seed, use: new RandomFactory(seed);
    RandomlyGeneratedInitialMeans init = new RandomlyGeneratedInitialMeans(RandomFactory.DEFAULT);

    // Textbook k-means clustering:
    KMeansLloyd<NumberVector> km = new KMeansLloyd<>(dist, //
    3 /* k - number of partitions */, //
    0 /* maximum number of iterations: no limit */, init);

    // K-means will automatically choose a numerical relation from the data set:
    // But we could make it explicit (if there were more than one numeric
    // relation!): km.run(db, rel);
    Clustering<KMeansModel> c = km.run(db);

    // Output all clusters:
    int i = 0;
    for(Cluster<KMeansModel> clu : c.getAllClusters()) {
      // K-means will name all clusters "Cluster" in lack of noise support:
      System.out.println("#" + i + ": " + clu.getNameAutomatic());
      System.out.println("Size: " + clu.size());
      System.out.println("Center: " + clu.getModel().getPrototype().toString());
      // Iterate over objects:
      System.out.print("Objects: ");

      for(DBIDIter it = clu.getIDs().iter(); it.valid(); it.advance()) {
        // To get the vector use:
         NumberVector v = rel.get(it);

        // Offset within our DBID range: "line number"
        final int offset = ids.getOffset(it);
        System.out.print(v+" " + offset);
        // Do NOT rely on using "internalGetIndex()" directly!
      }
      System.out.println();
      ++i;
    }
```

Comment: **Read the comments in the source code**... They are not just decoration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say, since you are using [`RandomlyGeneratedInitialMeans`](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/releases/release0.7.0/doc/de/lmu/ifi/dbs/elki/algorithm/clustering/kmeans/initialization/RandomlyGeneratedInitialMeans.html):

> Initialize k-means by generating **random vectors** (within the data sets value range).

```
RandomlyGeneratedInitialMeans init = new RandomlyGeneratedInitialMeans(RandomFactory.DEFAULT);
```

Yes, it is normal.

Comment: very nice... so should I replace it with another init or what!! *_*

Comment: No I want a stable result (since I want to cluster a set of resume)

Comment: You may want to investigate other subspace clustering techniques. A google search for "robust subspace clustering" produces promising results.

Comment: @Abeerzaroor I don't really have any vast experience/knowledge with this library, but I'm sure you can look online and in the documentation to find what you need if it exists

Comment: @AustinD I google it and I found that elki provides CLIQUE: Automatic Subspace Clustering of High Dimensional Data for Data Mining Applications, so should I use this instead of kmean? there is no way to make it more sable instead of providing random result? for example changing the initi type!! or this not making sense?

Comment: @Idos ok thanx very much for the answer I'm grateful :)))

Comment: I tried to lookup the init type and the constructor that uses the init for `KMeansLloyd<NumberVector>` but couldn't find anything meaningful (I can't really test this code myself without installing alot of stuff). Sorry I can't solve this, maybe open a different question targeting this specific problem will yield a result :)

Comment: you answered my question (the reason why I got a random output) now  my turn to look for another solution thanx veeeery much :)))

Answer (score 2):

K-Means is *supposed* to be initialized randomly. It is *desirable* to get different results when running it multiple times.

If you don't want this, **use a fixed random seed**.

From the code you copy and pasted:

```
// To fix the random seed, use: new RandomFactory(seed);
```

That is exactly what you should do...

```
long seed = 0;
RandomlyGeneratedInitialMeans init = new RandomlyGeneratedInitialMeans(
  new RandomFactory(seed));
```

Answer (score 0):

This was too long for a comment. As @Idos stated, You are initializing your data randomly; that's why you're getting random results. Now the question is, how do you ensure the results are robust? Try this:

Run the algorithm `N` times. Each time, record the cluster membership for each observation. When you are finished, classify an observation into the cluster which contained it most often. For example, suppose you have 3 observations, 3 classes, and run the algorithm 3 times:

```
obs R1  R2  R3
1   A   A   B
2   B   B   B
3   C   B   B
```

Then you should classify `obs1` as `A` since it was most often classified as `A`. Classify `obs2` as `B` since it was always classified as `B`. And classify `obs3` as `B` since it was most often classified as `B` by the algorithm. The results should become increasingly stable the more times you run the algorithm.

Comment: its would be nice to be able to observe my data since I have a large dataset of resume, I knew that the output very different each time from the number of elements in each cluster

Comment: last question in the code there is  // Iterate over objects// objects here refers to the data i.e. vector for each document\??

Comment: The classes are not stable and *will* permute. So on average, every object will be equally often in every class.